# Convert EDT timestamp to local time in React Native/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I get timestamp from server("2017-08-18T04:51:25EDT") which I want to convert to local time before displaying it to user. Can anyone show me how to achieve the same with moment.js or any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

Use react-moment and remove the EDT from your string (I actually don't know this type of date format and moment says it's invalid, so remove it and it works).

Here's an example how to use it:

```
let dateToFormat = '2017-08-18T04:51:25';
return (
   <Moment>{dateToFormat}</Moment>
)
```

Look at the docs of react-moment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment

Answer (score 0):

EDT does not seem to be a valid time zone identifier, as you can see when pasting it into this fiddle:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_date_new_string

Can you get the date as a UTC timestamp or something else which is accepted by new Date("DateString") ?

Otherwise you would have to cut the EDT from the time stamp string, create a new Date object from it and then add the time difference manually.

Converting the date objcet to a locale time string can then be done with

```
dateObj.toLocaleDateString([locales [, options]])
```

as you can see here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString